# Azure Data factory passing parameters to data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to pass Year, Month, Day from pipeline to dataflow and use these 3 parameter values in dataflow to read files from corresponding folder in ADLS.

To start with I have created 3 parameters at data flow level and used these 3 parameters in "Source" "Source Options" under wildcard paths but it's giving me error message as "not file/folder exists and is not hidden".

How can I pass the parameters from pipeline and use those values at dataflow level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure there's file/folder under wildcard paths. Then try this:

1. Create three parameters named Year, Month and Day in the pipeline.

[image]

2. Create the correspond parameters at data flow level.

[image]

3.Pass the parameters form pipeline to data flow.

[image]

4. Use this expression `concat('/',$Year,'/',$Month,'/',$Day,'/*')` in the Wildcard paths setting.

[image]