# can we use dataflow inside a for each loop in ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

can we use dataflow inside a for each loop in ADF ? If so then how can we pass the for each item into data flow parameters.

Answer (score 0):

yes, You can use dataflow within foreach
[image]

Comment: can you tell me how the for each items are passed into dataflow

Comment: dataflow parameter: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/121725/how-to-pass-parameters-from-a-pipeline-to-a-data-f.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68051596/azure-data-factory-passing-parameters-to-data-flow

for each :
https://azurelib.com/foreach-activity-in-azure-data-factory-with-practical-example/

Comment: @item().attributename